# Invite Twitter friends to iPhone application issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I want to invite friends from twitter to my application.

I've read the documentation from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios and from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth   . So now I can successfully sign on with twitter, get user information (token and login), can post twits to my wall.

But is posting twits with invitations only way to invite friends from twitter?

What is the best way to invite friends to my application?

Comment: Yes the only way is to post a tweet to your friends.

Comment: But how? I only know, how to post tweet to my own wall

Comment: If you know how to post a tweet, same method can be used for tweeting to friend by giving friend's id or screenname..

Comment: You can send direct message to your friends.

Comment: You can post a tweet to your friends or send the a direct messages :)